# How to remove text from a large string array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I have a large string of text and i need to remove all content before and after a certain section. I have an introduction section of text that starts with the word "introduction" an analysis section that starts with the word "analysis" and a conclusion section that starts with the word "conclusion". How can i remove or slice the string in such a way that i can display the analysis section on its own?

This is the loop i have been trying to use

```
for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i] === "analysis") {
        array.splice(i, 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an example input, your expected output, and the code that you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to _StackOverflow_! Its a **great** community! I think you may benefit from a [really good tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions here.

Comment: Maybe with a regex? (`(analysis[\s\S]+?)conclusion` https://regex101.com/r/s0TwHi/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on the word `conclusion` first, then split on the word `analysis`. Take that portion, and concatenation `analysis` back in:

```js
 

var text = "introduction - some words. analysis - some numbers. conclusion - more words";
var analysis = "analysis" + text.split("conclusion")[0].split("analysis")[1];
console.log(analysis);
```